# What are good sources to read stories similar to Ribhu Nidagha story ? focused on advaita vedanta

Tags: puranas

I am interested in stories in purana which are of nature of advaita vedanta. Thanks
I am looking for stories like Ribhu Nidagaha, which purana is recommended for this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: adhyatma ramayana?